# Monitoring folder and compile

Tags: scripting, compiling, monitoring

**Monitoring** the folder and when the `.CPP` file arrived inside the folder then **automatically compile** the program in **ubuntu**

can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: by "`.cpp` file arrived", do you mean when the source file first appears in the directory, or any time the file is modified?

Comment: when source file arrived in the folder which is automatically compile the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple case real monitoring (`inotify`) is probably overkill.

```
#! /bin/bash

file_path='/path/to/file.cpp'

while true; do
    if [ -f "$file_path" ]; then
         : do something
         exit 0
    else
         sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank you so much  you give me to what i want thanks again